# Not getting image from given source in jsp <img >tag

Tags: jsp

Hi i have created jfreechart and converted it to png file,now my problem is that i m storing that png image at context path,but when im going to add this image using  tag into jsp::: its not getting that img from appropriate path,,,my code is as follows,

```
{
    JFreeChart piechart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D("Division :GYNOSWIFT ",dataset,true,true,true);
           JFreeChart barchart = ChartFactory.createStackedBarChart("Stacked Bar Chart", "Division","Sale", dataset1, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, true);
           long timeVar = new Date().getTime();
           String filepath = getServletContext().getRealPath("//")+"\\images\\areachart"+timeVar+".png";
           String filepath1 = getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"\\images\\barchart"+timeVar+".png";
           final File file = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"\\images\\areachart"+timeVar+".png");
           final File file1 = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"\\images\\barchart"+timeVar+".png");
           ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file,piechart,400,400);
           ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1,barchart,600,400);


    im including path here::
    <table><tr><td><img src="<%=filepath%>"/></td></table>
    }
```

when i print path it is as ,E:\Amol\apache-tomcat-6.0.29\webapps\mis\images\areachart1318589620389.png

please suggest solution,thanx

Comment: first of all, don't if it helps your problem but use / instead of \ for url addresses like in filepath. E.g. "/images/areachart"+timeVar+".png"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String filepath = "/images/areachart"+timeVar+".png";
```

Assuming that "mis" is your project deployed in the tomcat, you want to use the relative path from your deploy to get the image, so your src should be the root (/) plus your folder (images/) plus your file name (areachart00000.png).

Or if your JSP is inside the "mis" folder, you can use only

```
String filepath = "images/areachart"+timeVar+".png";
```

as the relative path from your jsp.

Comment: You're welcome. (If you think it is the right answer accept it so others can benefit from your question too)